# OpenShift - S2I without source repository

Tags: git, build, openshift

I am working with an OpenShift cluster deployed on a laptop as`minishift`. When I make changes to my source code, I have to commit to the GitHub repository *before* I can trigger a build and a deploy. I am using the Source build strategy.

It seems a bit roundabout to commit to GitHub before I trigger a build and deploy on my local OpenShift cluster. One way I can think of is to have a GitLab based installation locally (at least, on LAN) to which code is committed. However, is there a way to do away with commit to GitHub/GitLab completely? Or a `git` repository is a minimum requirement?

Comment: You can use a binary input build, which pushes code from your local directory without needing Git. Suggest you read https://www.openshift.com/deploying-to-openshift/ which includes coverage of the topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried [GitLab CE on Ubuntu](https://about.gitlab.com/install/#ubuntu); but, for some reason the login page won't come up ever. So, I ended up using `git-http-server` [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/git-http-server); not ideal, but it does the trick.

:rolleyes: